# Get items that appear in all rdds - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm new to spark and I'm trying to filter a final rdd that contains items that appear in all others rdds.

My code

```
a = ['rs1','rs2','rs3','rs4','rs5']
b = ['rs3','rs7','rs10','rs4','rs6']
c = ['rs10','rs13','rs20','rs16','rs1']
d = ['rs2', 'rs4', 'rs5', 'rs13', 'rs3']

a_rdd = spark.parallelize(a)
b_rdd = spark.parallelize(b)
c_rdd = spark.parallelize(c)
d_rdd = spark.parallelize(d)

rdd = spark.union([a_rdd, b_rdd, c_rdd, d_rdd]).distinct()
```

Result: ['rs4', 'rs16', 'rs5', 'rs6', 'rs7', 'rs20', 'rs1', 'rs13', 'rs10', 'rs2', 'rs3']

My expected result is ['rs3', 'rs4']

Thank you!!!

Comment: I suggest you to read more about the documentation. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.distinct. Try to check the inner joins.

Comment: My bad, It did not find that API document page, I will spent more time on it Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you say you want an rdd that contains the items in all your rdds you mean the intersection? if that's the case you shouldn't use the union and the intersection of your rdds is empty (no element is repeated in your 4 rdds)

but if you need to do the intersection of your rdds :

```
    def intersection(*args):
         return reduce(lambda x,y:x.intersection(y),args)

    a = ['rs1','rs2','rs3','rs4','rs5']
    b = ['rs3','rs7','rs1','rs2','rs6']
    c = ['rs10','rs13','rs2','rs16','rs1']
    d = ['rs2', 'rs4', 'rs1', 'rs13', 'rs3']

    a_rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
    b_rdd = sc.parallelize(b)
    c_rdd = sc.parallelize(c)
    d_rdd = sc.parallelize(d)

    rdd = sc.union([a_rdd, b_rdd, c_rdd, d_rdd]).distinct()
    intersection(a_rdd, b_rdd, c_rdd, d_rdd).collect()
```

The output is ['rs1','rs2']

Comment: I have a suggestion to `reduce` you can add like this: `reduce(RDD.intersection, args)`

Comment: ah yes it's a more elegant way to do it :)